# How can I type sth in the blank between the printed word?

Tags: c, linux

I want to code a simple program which can 'communicate' with the user.
I want that users could type numbers or words in the blank which is ***between*** the printed words.

I want to make the interaction between user and computer more naturally and precisely. But I can't come up with an idea that can realize the goal.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a;
    printf("please tell me your download speed: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("So your download speed is %.2f Mb/s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Object display:**

```
"please tell me your download speed:          Mb/s"
```

(the cursor is located at the blank)

The user types `"5.2"` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
"So your download speed is 5.20 Mb/s"
```

Comment: For that type *field* control for input you will want to look at a curses library line `ncurses`. Otherwise there isn't a portable way to approach it at all because of the differences between terminals on different operating systems. There are some utilities like `tput` and (old ANSI escape sequences) that you can *hack* to make the cursor backup, but that is really not recommended. Without a curses library, better to just `printf ("please tell me your download speed (Mb/s): ");`

Comment: What system are you using? Linux? Windows? What terminal are you using? Moving cursor is an action outside of C standard, so specifying only "c" is not enough. It's an implementation/operating system/environment dependent thing. You have to see system dependent libraries to do that. Ex. there is a [windows api](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.8) and linux terminals use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: You can try to use the backspace character `\b`. It will set the cursor one character to the left on many terminals. Use as many of it as you see fit. But beware, this is super simple and will work only under limited conditions. In example, if your user enters more characters than you provided the input will overwrite your text.